# Create form for multiple/two NOT related models in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp, formhelper

I have two Models: ModelA, ModelB. They booth have id, name, ..., done(bool) fields.

ModelA does NOT relate any way to ModelB!

I created ONE Form, which have booth models fields in ModelA/add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('ModelA', [
...
]);

echo $this->Form->input('ModelA.name');
...
echo $this->Form->input('ModelA.done', [
    'default' => true
]);


echo $this->Form->input('ModelB.name');
...
echo $this->Form->input('ModelB.done', [
    'default' => true
]);
```

My problem, is that Cake does not create a checkbox for ModelB.done instead a simple input field.
Also it does not validates ModelB. (Because it does not know these fields relates to ModelB.)

I can do manually validation, by loading ModelB in ModelA controller and do something like: `$this->ModelB->validate(...)`

My question is: Is it possible to set that this Form has two not related model?

Comment: What does your code look like for saving the form data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to set two unrelated models and validate them without calling the validate function.

However, your checkbox issue could well be solved.

Use this:

```
   echo $this->Form->input('ModelB.done', [
    'type'    => 'checkbox',
    'default' => true
   ]);
```

Comment: It can be a comment rather than answer